# Nashorn: monkey patch a Java object?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Let's say I've an object instantiated from the following Java class:

```
class Pojo {
    public String foo = "foo";
}
```

This object is then bound to the Nashorn engine:

```
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("pojo", pojo);
```

If I try monkey patching the POJO, the following code prints `undefined`:

```
engine.eval("pojo.bar = 'baz'; print(pojo.bar);", bindings));
```

I assume this is because POJOs don't get converted to regular JS objects. Is there some other construct (provided by Nashorn?) that would let me achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't monkey patch Java.   So ... no, there there is no other way to do this to a Java object.  Suggest you use something like a `Map` that provides an API for adding entries.

Comment: I know. I was thinking more along the line of converting a POJO to JS object first ...

Comment: It would be simpler to just write it in JS to start with if this is the kind of thing you need.  (In my experience, it is counter-productive to try to "fight" the language. You end up with something that is harder for *other people* to understand and maintain.)